# Using Tile Palette with Background does not fit exactly on the boxes

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

am having problems with the design of my RPG 2D map. I found a city assets on the web which I am trying to use, however, whenever I try to paint any of the tiles generated automatically (sprite editor --> slice), they do not fit on mu background grid. They look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa8ZV.png)

I tried making a screenshot of my tilemap closer and then the problem was the opposite, my tiles were bigger than the boxes on my background grid.

Comment: So change the size of your tiles. Or the pixels per unit of the sprite